# where infopath file attachment are stored

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, infopath

I use infopath form,nearly i using 20 file uploaded in infopath form by each view(stages).where the uploaded file are stored?.when check in SQL library database and sharepoint library,there only textfield and datepicker are showing but file attachment not show in database and library.please can show where 20 uploaded file are store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, the files attached into an InfoPath form are saved into the same form as a string base64.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InfoPath with an associated list, the file should save directly to that list item.  But to make sure, go to Advanced Settings and in the middle of the page is Attachments - select "enabled".

[image]

Comment: But we use 20 attachment file...how it store on the list item?Because in sharepoint list, we store only one document as a list item on sharepoint list .